# No module named 'kivy'

Tags: python, error-handling, module, kivy, python-3.5

I've installed kivy on my laptop using an installer from GitHub and everything was ok, I always run my code by CMD, I use Pycharm to code but I've never tried to run my code through it until moments ago. In Pycharm, configuration, python interpreter, I changed  to "python 3.5(untitled)", Now my code runs in Pycharm, But I get following error in CMD:

C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop>kivytest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\kivytest.py", line 1, in 
    from kivy.app import App
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

I really need CMD, so what should I do now?!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Do you use the virtual enviroment? Can you add to your question commands that you use in CMD.

Comment: this is my command and what happens in cmd:C:\Users\ASUS>cd desktop

C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop>kivytest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\kivytest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Kivy is not installed in your current environment. I would suggest to follow the instructions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html to install kivy in your current environment. Once it is installed please try to run your code again.

Comment: I checked and kivy was already in the list, however I reinstalled it and it didn't help. I know that I've installed it on this environment. I really don't understand what has happened...

Answer (score 0):

So I uninstalled Pycharm and installed kivy in Visual Studio and the problem is kinda solved, though I don't understand what happened in the first place that caused this problem!